# python3 - can't pass through autorization

Tags: authentication, python-3.x, web-crawler, authorization

I need to build webcrawler for internal usage and I need to login into administration area. I'm trying to use requests lib, tried this ways:

```
import urllib.parse
import requests

base_url = "https://target.url"

data = ({'login': 'login', 'pass': 'password'})

params = urllib.parse.urlencode(data)

r = requests.post(base_url, data=params)

print(r.text)
```

and

```
import requests

base_url = "https://target.url"

r = requests.post(base_url, auth=('login', 'password')

print(r.text)
```

but in both cases r.text returns me login page content same as if I try to get any other page after auth code:

```
req = requests.get("https://target.url/smth")
```

What I lose sight of? I have ideas:

1. chain of hidden redirections from https://target.url to real login page, so I send auth info to wrong url
2. I don't send additional required info (like cookies e.g.)

Could you please comment? How can I gather required for login information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case problem was in 'Referer' parameter in headers, which is required but wasn't specified